# Wait Cursor not showing up on Win CE 6

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce

During a long process I show the hourglass/waitcursor using this code:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
```

This had worked on a Win CE 5 device, but when I ran the same program on Win CE 6 (also a separate device), the cursor won't appear. Though it appears just fine during lengthy processes (that I didn't code for), like launching a program.

Is this a difference between the OS versions, or the device? Anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Does your application listen for mouse events?

Comment: What do you mean? OnClick fires just fine, if that was what you wanted to know.

Comment: Have you seen the wait cursor in other applications? It may happen that the OS on your new device does not provide a default wait cursor at all.

Comment: Not other applications, but only because I haven't tried. Like I mentioned though, it does appear when launching a program.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
Cursor.Show();
```